# Facebook-like friend selection checkbox

Tags: html, css, facebook

I'm trying to code a selection like the Facebook "invite friends" selection. I like it because it uses the default checkboxes and not a background simulating the selection of each item.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how can they make the text (friend's name) break into two lines if needed (text is too big)!

I have a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li class="store_selectable">
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <a href="#">
        <div class="store-text">
          <div class="iblock"><img alt="Missing" src="http://placehold.it/30x30"></div>
          <div class="text"><div>This is the store</div></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

​

And here's the CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

li.store_selectable {
    width:161px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0px 6px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:0.9em;
}

li.store_selectable .checkbox {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:12px 6px 0;
}

li.store_selectable .store-text {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
}

li.store_selectable img {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px
}

li.store_selectable a {
    display:block;text-decoration:none;
    padding:2px;
    outline:none;
    color:#333;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-width:1px 0;
}

li.store_selectable a:hover {
    background:cyan;
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-width:1px 0;
}

li.store_selectable .iblock {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
}
```

For an easier testing and understanding I've created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rikas/tpqHd/1/

Now, what I'm trying to do is breaking the text in two lines if the width of the list item is small enough, changing this line: `width:161px;`. Messing with facebook "invite friends" modal window CSS I can see that they do it, but I can't!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of the interface you are trying to achieve, but the reason for text not wrapping is the css

```
     overflow:hidden;
```

after removing that consider putting your checkbox and 
the text its own div element with class .fl

```
    .fl { display:block; }
```

to line them side by side

directly under the two create another empty div element with the class of .clear

```
    .clear { display:block; clear:both; line-height:0; }
```

to prevent the next element inheriting the float:left